# SQL - aggregate related accounts - maually set up ID

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables:

- Account & Amount column
- list of related accounts

Data samples:

```
   Account |   Amount
   --------+---------
   001     |   $100
   002     |   $150
   003     |   $200
   004     |   $300

   Account |   Related Account
   --------+------------------
   001     |   002
   002     |   003
   003     |   002
```

My goal is to be able to aggregate all related accounts. From table two - 001,002 & 003 are actually all related to each other. What I would like to be able to do is to get a sum of all related accounts. Possibly ID 001 to 003 as Account #1, so I can aggregate them.

Result below

```
ID   | Account   | Amount
-----+-----------+--------
#1   |  001      | $100
#1   |  002      | $150
#1   |  003      | $200
#2   |  004      | $300
```

I can then manipulate the above table as below (final result)

```
ID   | Amount
-----+--------
#1   | $450
#2   | $300
```

I tried doing a join, but it doesn't quite achieve what I want. I still have a problem relating account 001 with 003 (they are indirectly related because 002 is related with both 001 and 003.

If anyone can point me to the right direction, will be much appreciated.

Comment: look for `recursive CTE`

Comment: @maSTAShuFu I looked into this and it referred to hierarchies. I sort of agree, but all the examples I looked at keeps referring to null manager - which I suppose gives you the top of the hierarchy. But my data doesn't have these nulls. Table two have accounts which definitely have a relationship.

Comment: Why do you have `002` tied to `003` twice, but only once to `001`?

Comment: Your sample data makes the solution very cumbersome. With a couple of small changes the solution can be simplified. Can you change the database structure or data?

Comment: You have a circular definition on 2 and 3.  What are the rules?

Comment: @ZoharPeled That's he thing, there are no particular rules. I have to find all accounts that are linked. It could be 4 accounts which could be linked by a single account. These are just accounts inserted in a note field - the service officer will insert the first related account they see.

Comment: @paparazzo this is not a database as such. I'm working with data entered by service officers. as per above message, the service officer is only required to input 1 related account, although 003 is also related to 001. But since 002 is already tied to 001. 003|001 entry is not required. The operator is able to work it out on the go, looking at the screen. But since I'm working with mass data, I need to work out a rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you really made this harder then it should be.
If you could change the data in the second table, so it will not contain reversed duplicates (in your sample data - 2,3 and 3,2) it would simplify the solution.
If you could refactor both tables into a single table, where the `related` column is a self referencing nullable foreign key, it would simplify the solution even more.

Let's assume for a minute you can't do either, and you have to work with the data as provided. So the first thing you want to do is to ignore the reversed duplicates in the second table. This can be done using a common table expression and a couple of case expressions.

First, create and populate sample tables (**Please** save us this step in your future questions):

```
DECLARE @TAccount AS TABLE
(
    Account int,
    Amount int
)

INSERT INTO @TAccount (Account, Amount) VALUES
(1, 100),
(2, 150),
(3, 200),
(4, 300)

DECLARE @TRelatedAccounts AS TABLE
(
    Account int,
    Related int
)

INSERT INTO @TRelatedAccounts (Account, Related) VALUES 
(1,2),
(2,3),
(3,2)
```

You want to get only the first two records from the `@TRelatedAccounts` table.
This is the **`AccountAndRelated`** CTE.
Now, you want to left join the `@TAccount` table with the results of this query, so for each Account we will have the Account, the Amount, and the Related Account or NULL, if the account is not related to any other account or it's the first on the relationship chain.
This is the **`CTERecursiveBase`** CTE.
Then, based on that you can create a recursive CTE (called **`CTERecursive`**), and finally select the sum of amount from the recursive CTE based on the root of the recursion. 
Here is the entire script:

```
;WITH AccountAndRelated AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT CASE WHEN Account > Related THEN Account Else Related END As Account, 
                    CASE WHEN Account > Related THEN Related Else Account END As Related
    FROM @TRelatedAccounts
)
, CTERecursiveBase AS
(
    SELECT A.Account, Related, Amount
    FROM @TAccount As A
    LEFT JOIN AccountAndRelated As R ON A.Account = R.Account
)
, CTERecursive AS
(
    SELECT Account As Id, Account, Related, Amount
    FROM CTERecursiveBase
    WHERE Related IS NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Id, B.Account, B.Related, B.Amount
    FROM CTERecursiveBase AS B
    JOIN CTERecursive AS R ON B.Related = R.Account
)

SELECT Id, SUM(Amount) As TotalAmount
FROM CTERecursive
GROUP BY Id
```

Results:

```
Id  TotalAmount
1   450
4   300
```

[You can see a live demo on rextester.](http://rextester.com/SQSO43340)

Now, Let's assume you can modify the data of the second table. You can use the `AccountAndRelated` cte to get only the records you need to keep in the `@TRelatedAccounts` table - This means you can skip the `AccountAndRelated` cte and use the `@TRelatedAccounts` directly in the `CTERecursiveBase` cte.
[You can see a live demo of that as well.](http://rextester.com/FSXQZ69039)

Finally, let's assume you can refactor your database. In that case, I would recommend joining the two tables together - so your `@TAccount` table would look like this:

```
Account Amount  Related
1       100     NULL
2       150     1
3       200     2
4       300     NULL
```

Then you only need the recursive cte. 
[Here is a live demo of that option as well.](http://rextester.com/NMDJO71427)

Comment: Reordering and making the combination unique on the Related Account Table worked very well. I learnt a lot - Thanks Zohar.